# Get http header in basic TCP server using linux system call

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, system-calls, recv

I have a basic TCP server which uses linux system calls (setsockopt , bind , listen , accept , recv ).
recv command returns me the request message which is nothing but complete URL.
Is there any way I can retrieve http header from the data recieve in recv system call?
Basically I want to extract user agent from the the http request. 
My code is a cpp cpde
-Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

HTTP does not contain the full URL per se. You need to put it together yourself from the Host header and the request URI.